# elasticsearch: max file descriptors [1024] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]

Tags: kubernetes, elasticsearch

When I tried to run the [logging aggregation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch) I found out the following error generated by elasticsearch:

```
[2018-02-04T13:44:04,259][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks ] [elasticsearch-logging-0] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max file descriptors [1024] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
[2018-02-04T13:44:04,268][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [elasticsearch-logging-0] stopping ...
[2018-02-04T13:44:04,486][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [elasticsearch-logging-0] stopped
[2018-02-04T13:44:04,486][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [elasticsearch-logging-0] closing ...
[2018-02-04T13:44:04,561][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [elasticsearch-logging-0] closed
[2018-02-04T13:44:04,564][INFO ][o.e.x.m.j.p.NativeController] Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started
```

BTW I am running a kubernetes cluster v1.8.0 on minions and 1.9.0 on masters using cri-containerd on Ubuntu machines 16.04.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the docs;
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/file-descriptors.html You will need to change ulimit on file handles available to the process.

To set the limit on file handles persistently, you can add this to the limits file;

```
# /etc/security/limits.conf

elasticsearch  -  nofile  65536
```

and restart the service. on Ubuntu it might be necessary to enable pam limits.conf

If you are using systemd, then these values are set in the `elasticsearch.service` files, but this is normally done by the installed packag. You can override those settings...

/etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service.d/override.conf

```
[Service]
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
```